# Find lift($E_{p^2}$) of an elliptic curve $E_p$ defined in field $F_p$ where $p$ is a prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elliptic-curves, cryptography

How to find $E_{p^2}$ of an elliptic curve $E_p$ defined over finite field $F_p$ where $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: Perhaps googling "Hensel's Lemma" can help.

Comment: If Ep:Y^2 = X^3 + 2X + 3 where p=7, now how should I find E(p^2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so we have $\,y^2=x^3+2x+3\,$ , so what I had in mind is to check particular cases, say:

$$y=1\Longrightarrow f(x):=x^3+2x+2=0\Longrightarrow x= 3\,\,\,\text{is a root}\,\,\pmod 7$$

Now, as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) , since $\,f'(3)\neq 0\,$ (i.e., a simple root), we can define

$$t=-\frac{f(3)}{7}f'(3)^{-1}=-5\cdot 29=-5=2\pmod 7\Longrightarrow s=3+2\cdot 7=17$$

is a root of $\,f(x)\pmod{7^2}\,$ , which means the pair $\,(17,1)\,$ satisfies the ellitpci curve in $\,\Bbb F_{7^2}\,$ ...

Note that the other root modulo $\,7\,$ of this case, which is $\,2\,$ , is a double one, so Hensel's lemma cannot help to lift it modulo $\,49\,$ as $\,f'(2)=0\pmod 7\,$ ...

Comment: Nice deduction Don +1

Comment: @DonAntanio shouldn't it be (17,1) that satisfies the curve?

Comment: Of course, @ANKIT: I mixedthose two. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks very much.